# Loop de backend.bundle.js en aplicación de React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-router-dom

Estoy en una simple aplicación de react en la que consumo una API rest en unos componentes pero me muestra este mensaje en consola de manera continua al realizar acciones como ir a un link, realizar un evento, etc...

A que se debe este loop y como se puede solucionar adjunto captura.

[image: Imagen correspondiente a los mensajes en consola]

Comment: Muy complicado saber... al menos comparte el código de como renderizas esa página, o el menu o algo... Dice algo con acceder a la `posicion 0`, o algo con una propiedad `owner`... tienes algo en el código que sea relevante respecto a esto?

Comment: Pipe como vas no no tengo algo que referencie ello no algop en cierta posicion ni algo con una prop owner